# How to override the default download directory in webdriverio in a mocha test?

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, mocha.js, webdriver-io

Currently I have the following `prefs` set in the `capabilities` of `wdio.conf`

```
capabilities:[{
'goog:chromeOptions': {
prefs: {
    'download.default_directory': downloadDir
     }}
}]
```

downloadDir is created as a global variable as:

```
global.downloadDir = path.join(__dirname, 'localDownload');
```

I have created another global variable `newDwnldDirPath` in `beforeTest` to dynamically create a folder based on the test case number for each test case which is being executed.

```
global.newDwnldDirPath = path.join('./newDwnldDir/'+matches[0]);
```

Where `+matches[0])` picks up the test case number by using a regex operation. This is working and I get the new download directory created with test case number each for the test case like the following:

```
..
/TEST001/
/TEST002/
..
```

What I would like to do is override the default download directory in the test case execution such that the downloaded file goes to the `newDwnldDirPath`

Test script (mochajs) sample:

```
it('Test case doing something TEST001', function () {

        BasePage.clickDownloadFile();

}
```

So once this is run the downloaded file should go to `newDwnldDirPath` which will be `/TEST001/` and continues as so on.

Is there a way we can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now what I found is the configuration in webdriverio doesn't allow us to change the `download.default_directory` configured in `prefs` in `capabilities` dynamically based on the execution of each test case script. The reason for this is that the `prefs` can't be modified or reload the session with new `prefs` once the webdriverio starts executing the test cases.

I have found a workaround for the requirements that is by using the `recursive-copy` npm package (FYR: https://www.npmjs.com/package/recursive-copy).

Currently I am creating a dynamic folder with the number of test case (test case id) and using it as a global variable `newDwnldDirPath`  in `beforeTest` in wdio.conf.js
`global.newDwnldDirPath = path.join('./newDwnldDir/'+matches[0]);`

(`matches[0] info on this is in the question`)

Then created a `util` for doing a `recursive copy` from source (`default_directory`) to destination (which is the `newDwnldDirPath` )

```
var copyFileRecursive = require('recursive-copy');
var options = {

    filter: [
        
        'filename*.txt'
    ],

    rename: function(filePath) {
        return 'newFilename.txt';
    },

};


copyFileRecursive(src,dest){
        copyFileRecursive(src, dest,options)
         .on(copyFileRecursive.events.COPY_FILE_START, function(copyOperation) {
            console.info('Copying file ' + copyOperation.src + '...');
        })
        .on(copyFileRecursive.events.COPY_FILE_COMPLETE, function(copyOperation) {
            console.info('Copied to ' + copyOperation.dest);
        })
        .on(copyFileRecursive.events.ERROR, function(error, copyOperation) {
            console.error('Unable to copy ' + copyOperation.dest);
        })
        .then(function(results) {
            console.info(results.length + ' file(s) copied');
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            return console.error('Copy failed: ' + error);
        });
    }
```

Then used this `copyFileRecursive` method in the test case script as
 `Util.copyFileRecursive(downloadDir,newDwnldDirPath);`
Where `downloadDir` is the default_directory for download which is the global variable and the `newDwnldDirPath` is the new download directory like ex: `newDwnldDir/TEST001` and so on.

The options parameter is optional and can be used if you would like to pass wildcard filename parameters, rename the files etc. There are many other options in that which can be found in the recursive-copy package documentation.